# Trying to solve Error TS2339: Property 'module' does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm playing with [this boilerplate](https://github.com/enaukkarinen/Browserify-TypeScript-Angular-Gulp--Boilerplate) and noticed that [tsd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd) was deprecated in favor of [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings), so I upgraded to it.

Here's my current set of packages

- typescript@1.8.9
- tsify@0.14.1
- typings@0.7.9

With typings I upgraded the type definition for Angular and now cannot compile the typescript files anymore, because of `TS2339`.

For example

> [14:15:05] Bundle error: src/features/beef/beef.controller.ts(18,9):
>   Error TS2339: Property 'module' does not exist on type
>   'IAngularStatic'.

Also seeing this error reported by Visual Studio Code, and downloaded the definition file from HEAD of the Github repo, it's the same that typings installed.

So, my question is, this is a definition bug? Is there something to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of migrating from tds to typings, I created a new application with typings and manually installed the dependencies. It worked!

Still not sure why the migration didn't work, but there's an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bug in `typescript@1.8.9`. My same codes compiled with no error under `typescript@1.8.7` but TS2339 under `typescript@1.8.9`.